# running watch file in to schedule

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Have a requirement of using batch file in Cognos to upload the output in SharePoint by using Windows batch file we are scheduling.

Here is my script:

```
@ECHO OFF

IF EXIST "D:\Dev\close report name-en-in" Call Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File 'D:\Dev\close\pwrshell.ps1'

GOTO END

:END
```

PowerShell script is used for uploading the script from source.

After running batch file the output is not uploaded to SharePoint (PowerShell script works fine when running alone).

Comment: Put some diagnostics in the PowerShell script: is it being called at all?

Comment: Also: why not do the file check in PowerShell and avoid the batch file entirely?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635982/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works or not, but there is a simple error in your script.

```
Call Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File 'D:\Dev\close\pwrshell.ps1'
```

should be

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File 'D:\Dev\close\pwrshell.ps1'
```

---

Here's some better ways to end the file.

```
exit /b [errorlevel]
```

This stops the script, and optionally set an `errorlevel`.

```
goto :eof
```

We don't need `:EOF` for this to work, `goto :eof` works standalone.

Comment: `call` just doesn't do anything here, but it's not an error (the keyword is for invoking other batch scripts in a way that they return to the caller after execution). `goto END`/`:END` also isn't incorrect, but doesn't have a purpose, b/c the script would behave exactly the same with the 2 lines removed.

Comment: `call` is used to call a subroutine or batch file, not designed for a powershell script

Comment: I'm aware of that. It still doesn't hurt when you use it on executables. That's not the issue the OP is facing.