# PowerShell run great but does not run as a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have a PowerShell script - it opens a MS Access database, run a VBA script, and later close itself. It runs greatly manually.
Scheduled user is in the 'Administrator' of the computer and E is a local drive.

However, when I schedule it as a Windows task, it hangs. Codes are below. Could anyone tell me what went wrong?

```
$Access = New-Object -Com Access.Application
$Access.OpenCurrentDatabase("E:\Audit\audit.accdb")
$Access.Run("fun_run")
$Access.CloseCurrentDatabase()
$Access.Quit()

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Access)
Remove-Variable Access
```

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635982/1630171).

Comment: Are you running the scheduled task with the `Run with highest privileges` option? That can cause permissions issues.

Comment: Please check Ansgar's link for some excellent troubleshooting steps. Aside from that, there's some info you left out that we would need to really be able to help here. What user context is the scheduled task running as? Is it running with highest privileges? Is the E: drive a local or mapped drive? Does that account being used have rights to logon as a batch job?

Comment: Scheduled user is in the 'Administrator' of the computer and E is a local drive.

Comment: (1) You should be scripting "fun_run" in powershell, using OLEDB or DAO or ODBC or whatever. "Access.Application" is a heavy object prone to this kind of problem. (2) You need to test if you can even open and close the A.A object. (3) Does the Administrator have a default printer installed?

Comment: I would suggest`VBScript`for the beginning. Almost vba, so you just have to make some small adjustments usually. Then migrate to powershell.