# PowerShell scheduled job to restart console application

Tags: scheduled-tasks, powershell-3.0

I am trying to use PowerShell scheduled job to logoff my machine at specific time.

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -Daily -At (Get-Date).AddMinutes(2)
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $Trigger -Name "LogoffComputer5" -ScriptBlock {
    shutdown /l /f
    Get-Process | Out-File -FilePath "c:\process.txt"
} -Credential $credential
```

I thought it is permission so I used `Invoke-Command` with credentials, also I used `shutdown` with full path.

I tried command as following

```
Start-Process "cmd.exe" "/C shutdown /l /f"
```

All the commands works from PowerShell but not from scheduled job.

```
Import-Module PSScheduledJob;
$jobDef = [Microsoft.PowerShell.ScheduledJob.ScheduledJobDefinition]::LoadFromStore('LogoffComputer5', 'C:\Users\wkassem\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs');
$jobDef.Run()
```

The above command works if I run from PowerShell.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635982/1630171).

Comment: My issue after debugging it seems that PowerShell scheduled job does not execute any command other than powershell commands (Restart-Computer -Force) worked but (shutdown /f) does not work. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: That would be very weird, since PowerShell can normally run external commands just fine. Try with full path and extension: `& C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe /f` or `& C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe --% /c "C:\Windows\system32\shutdown.exe /f"`. For further help we need more information.

Comment: Neither worked for me. the job doesn't execute any external command from outside powershell commands.

Comment: Software execution policies preventing command execution perhaps? Anyway, this doesn't seem to be a programming problem, so I suggest moving the question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).