# SSIS Script Task Open MS Access run Macro

Tags: ms-access, ssis

I have created a SSIS job to run a script Task that opens an access db, runs 2 macros, then closes the database.

The access database is creating a report that the users want emailed at 2 a.m.  Currently the access db is writing the report to a directory so SSIS can email the report.

At some point, the this access database will be converted fully over into SQL server either as a full SSIS job or SSRS report.  Unfortunately due to other projects this will not happen for at least a year.

The job run fines from visual studio on my desktop.

I have deployed the job to the SSISDB.   I have created credentials and proxy to run the SSIS package as a scheduled job. The scheduled job will run if the proxy is logged onto the server.  The job will not run if the proxy is not logged into the server.  The job returns an error:  "i" macro cannot run in disabled mode.

Everything googled says to make sure the database is a trusted location.  In the Access database we have gone into the trust center and added the "\\servername\filepath" to the trusted location and enabled macros.

This does not fix the issue.  The proxy user has to be logged into the server for the job to run.

We have tried to do this as a .bat file with task scheduler and end up with the same result. Only runs when the user is logged into the sever

What needs to be done so the job can run in the middle of the night without the proxy user logged into the server?

Office 365 Access
Windows Server 2019
Visual Studio 2019
SSIS package deployed as 2017

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Task Scheduler Problem - Run whether user is logged on or not is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54516837/task-scheduler-problem-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not-is-not-working). Also review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663480/windows-task-scheduler-doesnt-run-vbscript

Comment: I followed the instructions and created a vb script. vb script ran when I manually ran it.  When it was scheduled I could see the access laccb file get created and then removed in a couple seconds.  It should have been locked for 2 minutes.  This is the same thing we see when we get the "i" macro cannot run in disabled mode.

Comment: Sorry, I have nothing else. I had a scheduled VBScript but think I just locked my computer and never logged off unless IT said I had to for updates. Unfortunately, no longer in that situation so can't verify.