# Fixing (0x1) Error When Executing PowerShell Scripts Using Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, taskscheduler

I'm trying to run a PowerShell script that runs hourly.
When I run the script outside Task Scheduller it goes right, but when I try to run using task scheduller, it shows me an (0x1) error.

Here is how my task is configured:

[image: Task Configuration]

- *Action:* Start a Program
- *Program/Script:* `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- *Add Argument (Optional):* `powershell.exe -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \\C:\xampp\java_monitor.ps1`
- *Start in (Optional):* Empty

Does anyone knows what should I change or add to fix execution?

Comment: What user are you using for the task? Has the user the necessary rights to run PowerShell scripts?

Comment: For one thing: remove `powershell.exe` from the argument list. Also remove the leading backslashes before the script path. For further troubleshooting see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41635982/1630171).

Comment: I'm using an user with administrative privileges to run it.

Comment: admin user is not enough. log on with this user one time and set PowerShell policy repectively.